# Looking for stand alone map server

Tags: web-mapping, tiles

New to mapping tech.

Requirements:

- Stand Alone Server for offline use (will be an internal app) - No Mobile.
- Ability to add custom CSS class and hover information to US counties
- Programmatically interact with map
- - When user hovers over zip code, zoom into and highlight county on map

I saw TileMill and TileStream, but TileStream doesn't work with Node 0.6+ like TileMill.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

---

EDIT

Goal is something similar to: http://polymaps.org/ex/population.html

Comment: 'Maps on a Stick?' (can be a local drive) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27501/building-a-disconnected-web-based-mapping-application

Answer (score 1):

The requirement of

> Ability to add custom CSS class and hover information to US counties

Will cut out most traditional map servers (as well as most installs of Internet Explorer).

If you're locked into node 0.6+, you can either remove the engines entry from the package.json in TileStream, and it'll likely 'just work', or you can use TileStache.

Comment: TileStache is a possibility.  But is there a way around IE support.  I edited the question to show an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

do you really need nodeJS 0.6+ ?
maybe you should use nodeJS 0.4.9, you can have both but only one can run.

otherwise you should try Tilestache, it use python tech, so nodeJS won't be a prob.
Tilestache can also read MBtiles maybe you should take a look.